# Jwt expires when user logged in from another browser

Tags: reactjs, jwt, nestjs

I have an application that generates a JWT token for the user on logging in. But the problem is I want when loggeruser login from another device or browser he logged out from the first one.
I didn't find any helpful resource.
Any suggestions ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to keep track of your issued tokens in a database, then, when you are creating a new token, you simply mark the old tokens as expired (hence, the first session no longer works)

Answer (score 1):

The only way to implement something like this is to pretty much implement a session based login flow. JWTs are stateless, so you cannot invalidate one after sending it out. You'd need to keep track of what the current given token is, which as I said, it pretty much a session based auth flow